# Potential difference across a charged capacitor when an additional charge is given to its positive plate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

The entire question is:

```
A capacitor of capacitance of 10μF is charged to a potential 100V with a battery. The battery
is now disconnected, and an additional charge of 400μC is given to the positive plate of the
capacitor. What is the potential difference across the capacitor now?
```

So, I calculated the original charge across the capacitor which comes out to be 1000μC, from the equation Q = CV. What I don't understand here is the effect that the addition of charge will have on the capacitor. Will it induce the same amount of charge on the negative plate? I made that assumption, and considered the total charge of the capacitor as 1400μC now, and got the new potential as 140V. But, the answer to the question is given as 120V. So, I was curious as to what actually happens to the extra charge and how it is rearranged.

Comment: Do you know the electric field due to a charged sheet of charge (I am assuming that this a parallel plate capacitor. Find potential difference due to one plate, and then find the potential difference due to the other plate, and add them up.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I got it. Many thanks. That helped me solve the question, although, my doubt about how the charge rearranges itself is still unsolved. Or does it rearrange at all? I don't know whether it's possible to have different charges on two different plates of the capacitor. Any thoughts about that?